# How to integrate siren activation function to cnn

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, activation-function

I was trying to implement an autoencoder with periodic activation function - `siren` [Link](https://github.com/vsitzmann/siren). But I have found examples using only linear layer. In the paper they mentioned a custom Hypernetwork which uses CNN but i didn't understood how to use for my autoencoder.

- Is it possible to implement `siren` for CNN
- how to implement for my autoencoder code mentioned in the below. simply adding `sin()` as activation function doesn't work because the author mentioned a custom initialization and some other tricks to make the periodic activation work.

I am attaching the paper here - [Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.09661)

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        # encoder layers
        self.enc1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.enc2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.enc3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 16, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.enc4 = nn.Conv2d(16, 8, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        
        # decoder layers
        self.dec1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 8, kernel_size=3, stride=2)  
        self.dec2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2)
        self.dec3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 32, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.dec4 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 64, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.out = nn.Conv2d(64, 1, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    def forward(self, x):
        # encode
        x = F.relu(self.enc1(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.enc2(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.enc3(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.enc4(x))
        x = self.pool(x) # the latent space representation
        
        # decode
        x = F.relu(self.dec1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.dec4(x))
        x = F.sigmoid(self.out(x))
        return x
net = Autoencoder()
print(net)
```

Comment: you'll need to implement the special initialization method for your case.

Comment: @Shai the initialization is only showed for linear layers by author can we use the same for covn layers

Comment: a conv layer is a special case of a linear one. adaptation should be made, but it is possible

Comment: @Shai can you show me how can we do that, I am very new to this deep learning. i was trying to use siren as an autoencoder for denoising